# How can I replace fascia boards that are larger than available lumber?

Tags: wood, exterior

I have a few facia boards that need replacing. I live in an older home where the boards are a true 1x6. The problem is all the new boards are about 1/2 inch shorter and when I line up the groove there is about a half inch gap between the board and the roof. I have seen a 1x8 double plowed board online (Home Depot) that I could cut down but they all say not available. Does anyone have any suggestions as how or what to do to fill the gap?
TIA

Comment: There are specialty mills that supply the historic market who could sell you board in the correct size. This kind of thing is actually really common, especially with siding.

Comment: 1x8 boards are available in most all home stores and lumberyards.  They will rip them to whatever size you want for a small fee.

Comment: What "groove"? Your problem isn't clear. A good photo might save us all some confusion.

Comment: @isherwood where I live a lot of fascia from the 1970s has a horizontal groove maybe 1/2" or 3/8" deep cut into the back side an inch or so from the bottom edge that the soffit boards fit into.

Comment: If you need an honest 1x6, you have to buy a current era 2x8 (1.5 if that by 7-1/4 or so) and cut/plane it down, unless you can find a 5/4x8 to buy and cut/plane it down less, which you might be able to find from a serious lumber supplier, but not from most home centers.

Comment: Consider composite instead of wood.  1x8 or whatever. They are a good solution for fascia if you are not doing a meticulous historical restoration.  They are expensive but don't need painting, now or ever, and don't rot.   For a hard-to-reach prone-to-wetness location they are especially valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase a 1x8 board (3/4" x 7-1/2" actual) and rip it down to the required 6" of actual width.

I'm not sure about the "grooves" you're talking about, but my guess is that the existing fascia boards have a dado on the back side so a solid wood soffit piece can go into them.

- If you don't have solid wood soffits, then you don't need to worry about where this dado is.
- If you do have solid wood soffits, then you do need to line up this dado so it will fit around the existing soffits. You'll also need to ensure the dado is the proper width for the existing soffit.

If you purchase plain 1x8 material, you can rout the dado in at whatever size and location you need.

If you don't need the dado at all, then you can simply ignore the existing ones and not bother to add one to your replacement fascia.

If you find some fascia that has 2 dados, you'll probably find that they're different distances from the edge so you have two options for lining up with your existing soffits. Again, though, these are only necessary for a solid wood soffit. Any sort of vinyl, aluminum, or other, non-wood soffit will probably simply nail into the bottom edge of the fascia and doesn't need a dado at all.